# How to Remove "[Running] python -u" while running my code in Output (Code Runner)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

How to remove the [Running] python -u "e:\Cats\Brownie\Python\helloworld.py"?
I know, that code runner is doing this.
I want the output to come like this:

> Hello World!

But it's coming like this:

> [Running] python -u "e:\Cats\Brownie\Python\helloworld.py"
> Hello World!
> [Done] exited with code=0 in 0.29 seconds

You might ask "Why code runner? the Terminal is there right?" I also like the terminal but I don't wanna type "python helloworld.py" 10000 times I run my code.

Comment: Why would you have to type "python helloworld.py" 10000 times?  After you've done it once, up-arrow followed by Enter should redo the command.

Comment: I want to feel like a pro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could find the "`showExecutionMessage`" option in "settings", uncheck it:

[image]

Or add the following settings in "settings.json":

```
"code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
```

Run:

[image]